# How to output logger name in JGroups and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, java.util.logging, jgroups

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.2, with Logback, and using EhCache as the Hibernate second-level cache with JGroups 3.6.8.Final for distribution.  All of the log messages for `org.jgroups` loggers are coming out as `unknown.jul.logger`.  This originates in the [SLF4JBridgeHandler](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) that Spring Boot installs to bridge java.util.logging loggers over to SLF4J.

Is there something I can do to have the logger name propagated over to the SLF4J logger?  When I was using JGroups 3.1.0.Final it was working fine, but after the upgrade all I get is the unknown logger.

Comment: I was unable to figure this out.  What I finally did was implement my own custom LogFactory for JGroups.  You can look at `org.jgroups.logging.LogFactory` to see how to do it.  I bridged it over to a true SLF4J loger and now everything works properly.

Comment: did you tried replacing that with log4j over sl4j .. though I prefer custom solution ..

Answer (score 0):

Since jgroups 3.6.x I switched to the following configuration (slf4j + log4j2).

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How does that help?  Wouldn't you also need Log4j's jul adapter? And I would think you would need the jcl adapter to handle Spring's logging.